# How to HTML ENCODE values in a GridView when Updatating - Error: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have GridView and I need HTML ENCODE all values being update using Event handler _RowUpdating.

At the moment I use this script BUT I receive an error:

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

---

Any idea how to make it works? Thanks for your help!

```
       foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in e.Keys)
        {
            e.Keys[entry.Key] = Server.HtmlEncode(entry.Value.ToString());              
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three options:

1) Take a copy of all the entries to start with, so you're not actually iterating over those and modifying them as you go.

2) Just iterate over a copy of the *keys* - again, to avoid modifying what you're iterating over.

3) Build a new dictionary instead of modifying the existing one.

Given the skeleton code here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Test
{    
    static void Main()
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "X", "first" },
            { "Y", "second" },
            { "Z", "third" }
        };

        // INSERT DICTIONARY-CHANGING CODE HERE            

        foreach (var entry in dict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

... and taking "upper-casing" as a simple thing to test (just use `Server.HtmlEncode` in your real code), here are the three options (I'm assuming you have LINQ available to you):

1) Iterating over a copy of the entries:

```
    foreach (var entry in dict.ToList())
    {
        dict[entry.Key] = entry.Value.ToUpperInvariant();
    }
```

2) Iterating over a copy of the keys:

```
    foreach (string key in dict.Keys.ToList())
    {
        dict[key] = dict[key].ToUpperInvariant();
    }
```

3) Creating a new dictionary (and then assigning the reference back to the `dict` variable):

```
    dict = dict.ToDictionary(entry => entry.Key,
                             entry => entry.Value.ToUpperInvariant());
```

Comment: HI thanks, are you able to provide me a sample of code? I am new in asp.net thanks

Comment: @GIbboK: Done - have a look now, and let me know if any of it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

That means can't modify items that you're iterating; create a new dictionary and copy items there then set that back after you're done looping.