# Iterate through the NewValues collection and HTML encode all

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Gridview and I try to Iterate through the NewValues collection and HTML encode all.

I am following [MSDN CODE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.aspx).... using their code (posted here) I receive an error:

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

I would like ask you a Full simple example how to implement it, so beginners like me can start use this function.
PS: I posted a similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591414/how-to-html-encode-values-in-a-gridview-when-updatating-error-collection-was-m) and people replied but I still do not understand it and i Would need a simple example.

```
    <%@ Page language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">

  void CustomersGridView_RowUpdating(Object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
  {

    // Iterate through the NewValues collection and HTML encode all 
    // user-provided values before updating the data source.
    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in e.NewValues)
    {

      e.NewValues[entry.Key] = Server.HtmlEncode(entry.Value.ToString());

    }

  }

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
  <head runat="server">
    <title>GridView RowUpdating Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

      <h3>GridView RowUpdating Example</h3>

      <!-- The GridView control automatically sets the columns     -->
      <!-- specified in the datakeynames property as read-only.    -->
      <!-- No input controls are rendered for these columns in     -->
      <!-- edit mode.                                              -->
      <asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
        datasourceid="CustomersSqlDataSource" 
        autogeneratecolumns="true"
        autogenerateeditbutton="true"
        allowpaging="true" 
        datakeynames="CustomerID"
        onrowupdating="CustomersGridView_RowUpdating"  
        runat="server">
      </asp:gridview>

      <!-- This example uses Microsoft SQL Server and connects  -->
      <!-- to the Northwind sample database. Use an ASP.NET     -->
      <!-- expression to retrieve the connection string value   -->
      <!-- from the Web.config file.                            -->
      <asp:sqldatasource id="CustomersSqlDataSource"  
        selectcommand="Select [CustomerID], [CompanyName], [Address], [City], [PostalCode], [Country] From [Customers]"
        updatecommand="Update Customers SET CompanyName=@CompanyName, Address=@Address, City=@City, PostalCode=@PostalCode, Country=@Country WHERE (CustomerID = @CustomerID)"
        connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthWindConnectionString%>"
        runat="server">
      </asp:sqldatasource>

    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
object[] keys = (object[])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), e.NewValues.Count);
e.NewValues.Keys.CopyTo(keys, 0);

foreach (object key in keys)
{
    e.NewValues[key] = Server.HtmlEncode(e.NewValues[key].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change collection while iterating through it using foreach loop.

```
 foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in e.NewValues)
{
  e.NewValues[entry.Key] = Server.HtmlEncode(entry.Value.ToString());
}
```

You are iterating through *e.NewValues* and changing it in next line. 
You have to create copy of e.NewValues, change it and then assign e.NewValues with the changed copy.

You could use a for loop:

```
for (int i=0; i< e.NewValues.Count; i++)
{
  DictionaryEntry entry = (DictionaryEntry)e.NewValues[i];
  e.NewValues[entry.Key] = Server.HtmlEncode(entry.Value.ToString());
}
```

*** EDIT:
It doesn't work, I tried to cast e.NewValues to DictionaryEntry with no success. On the other hand the code posted by GIbboK works fine.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz, I understand you explanation BUT your script for (int i=0; i< e.NewValues.Count; i++) .... seems does not work. Could you please post it another time, or a full version so I would be abel to use it? thanks

Comment: I tried to fix it, but I was unable to iterate with a 'for' loop. On the other hand this works fine:
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in e.NewValues)
            {
                e.NewValues[entry.Key] = Server.HtmlEncode(entry.Value.ToString());
            }

Maybe there's something else wrong with your code

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to work using Tomasz's approach (the iteration worked fine and looked like the values were updated, but the actual change did not take affect for the new values).

I performed the change on the DataSource control instead:

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Updating(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e) {
    foreach (DbParameter parameter in e.Command.Parameters) {
        parameter.Value = Server.HtmlEncode(parameter.Value);
    }
}
```